# PATCH:projects/users with several services

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360, bim

I am currently trying to update the user permissions on a project with the function `PATCH: project / users (v2)` for several services (BIM Docs, Field, Glue, Plan and Schedule) but for other services that Docs I have an error telling me that the services are invalid.

[Code documentation here.](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-user_id-PATCH/)

When I put only the permissions for project administration and Docs, it works.

However, i want to use the other services. So, when I set permissions for Docs, the rights for others are removed.

After several searches, I can't find a way to perform this command in cURL.

Here is the content:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-H "x-user-id: %user_admin_id%" 
-H "Authorization: Bearer %TOKEN%" 
-X PATCH https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v2/accounts/:account_id/projects/:project_id/users/:user_id 
-d '{
"services":
     {"document_management":{"access_level":"user"},
      "field_management:{"access_level":"user"}
},
"company_id":"%company_id%",
"industry_roles":["0b74b631-0a08-49ad-8f44-ada57d7de051"]
}'
```

Here the error :

> "error":[{"message":"Invalid services
>   [\"field_management\"]","code":2000}]

I already tried `field` instead `field_management`.

Any solutions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not set permission through API, yet.

You can set a service to a project:
 https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-POST/

services-type parameter.

You also need to have a license to those sub services.

Comment: Thank you. 

We have license for all sub services.

I knew for the POST function but before doing that I wanted to know if it was possible to do it by the PATCH command.